# Needed: "Good" MongoDB and/or Cassandra example application

Tags: mongodb, cassandra

I'm investigating both Cassandra and MongoDB for a new project because they share some good qualities that I will need to take advantage of for this project.

I've seen plenty of shallow examples for Cassandra and MongoDB - basically how to configure and start up the database, how to add new items, how to query the items.  But what I really need are examples that contain strategies for inserting and querying complex data.  Something that would require one-to-many and many-to-many relationships.

Actually I *did* find a Cassanrda/Twitter example that was pretty good [here](http://www.rackspace.com/cloud/blog/2010/05/12/cassandra-by-example/).  Where can I find more examples like this? ...especially for MongoDB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please look at

http://www.10gen.com/video

There are various postings and videos explaining MongoDB from scratch including examples.

Also look at

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Schema+Design

Key remarks:

- no JOINs
- use embedded documents otherwise or look at database reference
- denormalization is kind of common

Anything else you need?